# Fixing Pip versions and paths

Tags: python, macos, visual-studio-code, terminal, pip

How do I remove pip versions and aliases? (macOS)

I did `alias pip=pip3` but do not know how to remove it.

I also have pip, pip3.8 and pip3.9 install in `/usr/local/bin/` and want to delete 3.8 (I think) but do not know how.

all of this is in an attempt to figure out why my package is not working properly (all but one are importing). I see the correct package installed in my /usr/local/bin folder with all the pip and python versions but when I run my script in VSCode it says "Module Not Found".

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Naked.tooshed'
```

I just installed python 3.9 using the downloader on the python.org site.

any help on how to clean up my python & pip versions and pathing would be greatly appreciated

Comment: How are things going? Please let us know if there is any progress.

Answer (score 0):

1. Please check the spelling of the code:

> import Naked.toolshed

2. Usually, Python comes with pip installation tool, When using it to install a module, we can check its source (`pip --version`or `pip3 --version`) in the terminal, and then use it to install the module: (we can use the shortcut key Ctrl+Shift+` to make the VSCode terminal enter the currently selected [Python environment](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments))

   [image]

   [image]